# Replacing repeated values in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm coding a function in C to check if an array has any duplicate value, and if so replace it by any of the non-present ones. The array consists of numbers shuffled from 1 to Nmax:

```
unsigned char * NotRepeated (unsigned char *arr){

    unsigned char i, j, count, k, notrepeated[Nmax];

        k = 0;  
        for (i = 0; i < Nmax ; i++){ 
            count = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < Nmax; j++){ 
                if (arr[j] != i + 1){
                    count++;
                }
                if (count == Nmax){
                    notrepeated[k] = i + 1;
                    k++;
                }       
            }                       
        }   
        k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < Nmax - 1; i++){ 
            for (j = i + 1; j < Nmax; j++){

                if (arr[i] == arr[j]){
                    arr[j] = notrepeated[k];
                    k++;
                }
            }   
        }   
return arr
}
```

If I print the array `notrepeated[k]` I get almost all the array filled when the original array `arr[j]` seldomly has more than 2 repeated figures.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If you first sort your array, you could do two things: 1) read the last element of the array to get the maximum value; and, 2) read through the elements of the array in order, and test if the value of the current element is equal to the previously seen element — if so, replace with maximum value + 1, + 2, and so on, as you walk through the array, which are guaranteed to not already be in the array.

Comment: Could you upgrade your code fragment to a [mcve]?

Comment: Just updated it @Yunnosch, thanks